# Is there way to show a web page without iframe inside Firefox OS App?

Tags: jquery-mobile, firefox-os

I'm trying to develop an Firefox OS which shows my online Webapp page.
I wrote a code below which shows webapp content inside iframe.
My webapp uses jQuery mobile and it doesn't work properly inside iframe, because it refers the history of parent html.
Is there another way to show webapp or way to work jQuery mobile properly?
Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul role="tablist" id="tabs">
     <li>
       <a href="#panel1" class="TabIcon"></a>
       <div role="tabpanel">
         <!-- Web app iframe -->
         <iframe src="http://mywebapp.com/content/"></iframe>
       </div>
     </li>
     <li>...</li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your app is a privileged app you could add the mozbrowser attribute to the iframe which isolates the content a bit more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Browser

Alternatively you could try to implement the whole app as a single hosted app rather than wrapping parts in iframes and use appcache for the parts you want to access offline.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting window.location?

```
<html>
<script>
  window.location = 'http://www.example.com';
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My app is tabbed app which contains shows another locations, local file and online contents. window.location will not work since it shows location contents in a full window and user will not be able to get back to app.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve what you're looking for is to use an iframe. Actually every applications in firefoxos are being run within iframes.

What you need is to add the `Browser` permission to your application and use the iframe with the `mozbrowser`. If the `mozbrowser` attribute isn't enough, you could also add the `remote` attribute to force the iframe to be loaded in a different process.

```
   <div role="tabpanel">
     <!-- Web app iframe -->
     <iframe src="http://mywebapp.com/content/" mozbrowser="true" remote="true">
     </iframe>
   </div>
```

More information on the mdn website here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Using_the_Browser_API